# Construct Query to database dynamically

Tags: f#

I am currently using [FSharp.Data.SqlClient](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/), but I am interested in any solution of my task.

I have a web client and the backend written in F#.  In the web client user can set 10-20 filters and make the GET request to my F# backend. The URL looks like:

```
http://mybackend.com/get/1/0/34/ ....
```

Any number in this URL is a filter. There is no filter on the corresponding field if the value of corresponding filter is zero.

Now I need to construct the SQL query in my backend.  While the number of possible filters was 3-4 I was using pattern matching:

```
type GetEObyOrg1Org2AsutpParent = SqlCommandProvider<"SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE ORGID1 = @org1 AND ORGID2 = @org2 AND ASUTPID = @asutp AND PARENTAUTOINCID = @parent", "name=MobileConnectionProvider", ResultType.Tuples>
type GetEObyOrg1Org2Org3AsutpParent = SqlCommandProvider<"SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE ORGID1 = @org1 AND ORGID2 = @org2 AND ORGID3 = @org3 AND ASUTPID = @asutp AND PARENTAUTOINCID = @parent", "name=MobileConnectionProvider", ResultType.Tuples>

match (asutpid, orgId1, orgId2, orgId3) with

    | "0", _, "0", "0" -> 
        let cmd = new GetEObyOrg1Org2AsutpParent()
        cmd.Execute(org1 = orgId1, parent = parentAid)

    | "0", _, _ , "0" ->
        let cmd = new GetEObyOrg1Org2Org3AsutpParent()
        cmd.Execute(org1 = orgId1, org2 = orgId2, parent = parentAid)
```

But when the number of filters is greater then 3-4 it is very difficult to write pattern matching for all combinations of the parameters.

I think I need to construct the SQL query dynamically.  Each non-zero parameter in the URL must add `AND Field = Value` expression to SQL statement. But I can not do it:

```
type GetEObyOrg1AsutpParent = SqlCommandProvider<Query, "name=MobileConnectionProvider", ResultType.Tuples>
```

`Query` paramter is this expression **must be Literal**, and **I can not to construct literal expression dinamically**:

```
[<Literal>]
let q1 = "SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE ORGID1 = @org1 AND ASUTPID = @asutp"
[<Literal>]
let q2 = " AND PARENTAUTOINCID = @parent"

let f a = 
    match a with 
    | 1 -> q1 + q2
    | _ -> q1

[<Literal>]
let q3 = f()
```

What is the best way of doing it in my case ?

Comment: Just use a list [asutpid; orgId1; orgId2; orgId3] instead a tuple (asutpid, orgId1, orgId2, orgId3) so it is flexible in size.

Comment: Use it where? In pattern mathing expression? `match [asutpid, orgId1, orgId2, orgId3] with` ? But it doesn't solve my problem. In the case of 10 parameters I need to have 2^10 queries, types and pattern matching cases.

Comment: Then why not parse the filter sequence "1-0-34-42" ? Why do you append the filter(-codes) in the path/route?

Comment: I can parse the sequence `1-0-34-42`.  It is not the problem.  But in the result I need to execure SQL query.  If I will parse sequence (or anything else), my SQL Query will be constructed dinamically.  Right?  But `SqlCommandProvider` get the query as literal (and only literal).

Comment: Have you seen http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/sqlenumprovider.quickstart.html

Comment: Yes, I have seen.  But how can it helps me? All the queries in the examples have predefined number of parameters: `WHERE ShipDate > @shippedLaterThan AND ShipMethodID = @shipMethodId`.  In my case I don't know in the compile time how many and which ones of the parameters will be.

Comment: I have found solution - just use `System.Data.SqlClient` from the Net Framework. I believe it will work, but in this case I will not have type checking.

Comment: Why not put the zero-parameter also in the fixed query, to have type checking?

Comment: Becase `select * from t where f = "0"` and `select * from t` returns different sets of records.  The zero is not value to filter. It is just way to say - there is no filter.

Comment: For each id you could filter on `(id = f OR f = 0)`

Answer (score 1):

I think in a case like this the core library's `SqlDataConnection` type provider might be a better fit.  Then you should be able to use standard `IQueryable` operations to dynamically add additional `WHERE` clauses, something like:

```
type MyDb = SqlDataConnection<...>
let items = MyDb.GetContext().Item
let q1 = if asutpid = 0 then items else items.Where(fun i -> i.Asutpid = asutpid)
let q2 = if orgId1 = 0 then q1 else q1.Where(fun i -> i.OrgId1 = orgid1)
...
```